# Listing a number twice in a list box when pulling data from a database using the and key word in the sql statment in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

Sorry for the large heading, I don't know what is going on with my code. I am pulling all serial numbers for a given work order number and status code and populating a list box with the results. My issue is, my code is pulling the number but listing it twice in the list box control. I am using a postgres database. Here is my code.

```
 private void Get_Serial_Numbers()
    {
        NpgsqlConnection conn = Connection.getConnection();

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select product_serial_number from master_product where product_wo_number = :WorkOrder and status = :Status;", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("WorkOrder", IdStorage.WorkOrderNumber));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("Status", 128));

            NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            while (dr.Read())
            {
               object serialNumber = dr["product_serial_number"];
               lstProductsInWO.Items.Add(serialNumber.ToString());
            }

            if (lstProductsInWO.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                lstProductsInWO.Items.Add("No Data");
                lblSerialInWO.Text = "Products in WO 0";
            }
            else
            {
                ProductTotal = lstProductsInWO.Items.Count;
                lblSerialInWO.Text = "Products in WO " + ProductTotal.ToString();
            }


            dr.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Maybe change your query to `select distinct ...`?

Comment: Serial numbers are unique there can not duplicates.

Comment: I run the sql statement in postgres and get the one result, not sure why its pulling it twice in my C# program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possilities:

1. You accidently call the method Get_Serial_Numbers() twice in some event handlers - check it by debugging to make sure that the code runs only once.
2. You get the items twice from the table. Verify what the query returns (under the debugger) or running it manually against the database.